# mysql distinct or group by

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(player2) FROM logs 
WHERE player1=3 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Would it be possible to return other non-distinct cols with that query?

Or my other solution:

```
SELECT * FROM logs 
WHERE player1=3 
GROUP BY player2 ORDER BY time DESC
```

This works fine but it does not order properly. It picks the first one of the group.

Table example:

```
player1 player2 time
3        5        1
3        5        2
3        6        3
```

I would expect it to return:

```
player2 time
5        2
6        3
```

But it returns (with group by):

```
player2 time
5        1
6        3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT player2, MAX(time) AS time
  FROM logs 
 WHERE player1=3 
 GROUP BY player2 
 ORDER BY time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT player2, max(`time`) as max_time
FROM logs 
WHERE player1 = 3 
GROUP BY player2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT player2, MAX(time) AS time   
FROM logs   
WHERE player1=3  
GROUP BY player2   
ORDER BY MAX(time)
```

Comment: @Chandu I'm new. When I have a reivsion to an answer, is it best to edit the previous or add my own? Thanks